# WS02 API Manager Fault and Error Message Payload Structure Change

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Mavens,

I have managed to change the response for fault and error from xml to json using the below link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Error+Handling

However, I am now left with how to change the payloads for the faults or errors generated by the system itself

Something which is generated by default from the system

```
{ "fault": { "code": 900901, "message": "Invalid Credentials", "description": "Access failure for API: /employee/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials" }}
```

to something customized like this

```
{ "status": "fault", "description":{ "code": 900901, "message": "Invalid Credentials", "description": "Access failure for API: /employee/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials" }}
```

Update 1 :
Having a look at: https://medium.com/@azinneera/transforming-backend-error-messages-in-wso2-api-manager-91bf8d744ad4

Comment: looks like you only want to change the json structure of the error message, if that is the case you can do it by engaging a payload factory mediator in a custom API sequence in the  fault flow.

Comment: change the structure by adding/removing the fields. Yes. DO you have any links for me ?